# JQuery load script on event (click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#selector').click(function() {
    // here I would like to load a javascript file
    // let's say /js/script-on-click-event.js
});
```

Is that somehow possible? I'm not sure but I remember reading about a function that does this in JQuery documentation but I cannot find it here, maybe it's been deprecated or I saw it elsewhere?

Basically what I want is to load a script on a click event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like 
[jQuery.getScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript#urlcallback)

```
$("#selector").click(function(){
  $.getScript("http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/color/jquery.color.js");
});
```

Comment: hi @vsync, will it appends into **DOM** multiple times? please tell

Comment: @EaB - good question. see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108063/104380) for more information. `getScript` doesn't append anything to the DOM, but it will download the script and execute it every time `getScript` for the *same* URL is called. You should place your own safety mechanism to prevent such a thing.

Answer (score 10):

You can do the same using only javascript:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://somesite.com/somescript.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.body.parentNode.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

A library that makes this work is [LAB JS](http://labjs.com/)