# Load html template script on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a template `<script>` in my html:

```
 <script>
         window.daySelected = window.currentdate;
         window.monthSelected = window.currentmonth;
         window.yearSelected = window.currentyear;
 </script>
```

Here is an example of an external script file loading on a click event: [Jquery load script on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369014/jquery-load-script-on-a-click-event).

Is there a way to load the template script in my html on a click event?

Comment: This is already loaded if it is in your HTML.  have you tried inspecting your window.daySelected after your page loads?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because if you want to _execute_ this script on the click event, wrap it in a function and call it onclick:

```function setDates(){
    window.daySelected = window.currentdate;
    window.monthSelected = window.currentmonth;
    window.yearSelected = window.currentyear;
}``` and ```<img src='blah' onclick='setDates()' />```

Comment: @ZachM. I am trying to delay the script load.

Comment: Okay. Will try it now. @RickvandenBosch

Comment: Do what Rick said, wrap it in a function and call it on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a whole `javascript` file do this

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "url"; // replace url with actual url of script
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

To add a small `script` from `string` form

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHtml = "script"; // replace script with actual script
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

You could also just create a function

```
function onClick() {
    // insert your code
}
```

And you can call it by doing `onClick();` using `JavaScript`

You can also call it from a button by doing `<button onclick="onClick()">Click Me</button>`

Finally you can also call it from a anchor element by doing `<a href="javascript:onClick()">Click Me</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Create a script element and append it into your head tag like the following

```js
function addVals() {
  var sc = document.createElement("script");
  sc.innerHTML = "window.daySelected = window.currentdate; window.monthSelected = window.currentmonth; window.yearSelected = window.currentyear;";
  document.head.appendChild(sc);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addVals()" value="click me" />
```